# How to add custom field in catalog price rule and cart price rule?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules, sales, magento-2.1.8

I've custom module of banner.

I want to add banner id as drop-down in price rules to select as custom field.

When, I select banner Id during sales rule then the particular banner must be activated on the website.

How can I do?

Comment: it will not save to database right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to add new field in **`Cart Price Rule`**,  You need to create **`ui_component`** cause it created using it.

Follow Steps to add Custom Field in **Cart Price Rule**.

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_rule_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="rule_information" sortOrder="10">
    <field name="custom_field" formElement="select">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sales_rule</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Custom Field</label>
            <dataScope>custom_field</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
        <select>
        <settings>
            <options class="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Locale\Country"/>
        </settings>
        </select>
</formElements>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

Clear cache using `bin/magento c:c`, Than check.

Comment: Can I add this in my exisitng custom module or create new module?

Comment: You can do this in existing module.

Comment: but it is not working

Comment: Did you clear cache ? What error are you getting ?

Comment: Yes, cache clear. not getting any error on price rule section.

Comment: Paste your code in question. So i need to check your code.

Comment: I have created new directory in my custom module as you mentioned, then paste your code in that file.

Comment: @VinodKumar, Check properly You must made any typo, Cause i have tested in my system its working out of the box. Still compare directory structure i gave you. Also remove **var/generation, setup:upgrade, s:s:d, clear cache**

Comment: Did it work for you ? If not Are you on Magento 2.1.8 ?

Comment: I am checking on magento 2.2.4

Comment: Thanks, custom field has been added in shopping cart price rule. Can it be save in db?

Comment: @VinodKumar, 

Regarding Save , Its little bit change of topic If you want you can post a new question , I will try to answer it or someone else will.